# Populate <img> with source created dynamically with Java

Tags: java, jsp, internet-explorer-7, data-uri-scheme

I'm using Java to create dinamically images and put them into a jsp page.
This works fine in all browsers, except for IE 7. 
I'm using Data URIs in my jsp to populate  tags (I'm using a base64 string).
I've found many solutions for IE, but no one refers to images dinamically created in Java. 
This is one of the solutions found with css:

```
/*
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="MYSEPARATOR"

--MYSEPARATOR
Content-Location: myimage
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAADCAIAAAA7ljmRAAAAGElEQVQIW2P4DwcMDAxAfBvMAhEQMYgcACEHG8ELxtbPAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

--MYSEPARATOR--
*/

#test1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image:url(mhtml:http://......./test.css!myimage);
}
```

It works but I can't change in css the base64 string dinamically. 
How can I solve this problem for explorer 7?
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

For solution to this problem You can try the following things:-

1. First of all see that the html version you are using is html4 or html5 because these both support cross browse compatability.

2.Try changing CSS Transparency settings for all browsers.

Try using the following code:-

```
a.transeffect:hover {

filter:alpha(opacity=50);

-moz-opacity:0.5;

-khtml-opacity: 0.5;

opacity: 0.5;
}
```

If the above code doesn't work then try by removing the `-khtml-opacity: 0.5;` line from the code.